# Docker image failing to run

Tags: docker

I have built a docker image and now when trying to run the container I receive the following error message:

```
$ docker run myimage
[dumb-init] /docker-entrypoint.sh: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Also the file `docker-entrypoint.sh` exists on the image:

```
$ docker run --entrypoint=/bin/ls myimage -l /docker-entrypoint.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 724 Aug 23 09:50 /docker-entrypoint.sh


FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Gareth Rushgrove "gareth@puppet.com"

ARG ssh_prv_key
ARG ssh_pub_key

ENV PUPPET_SERVER_VERSION="2.7.2" DUMB_INIT_VERSION="1.1.0" UBUNTU_CODENAME="xenial" PUPPETSERVER_JAVA_ARGS="-Xms256m -Xmx256m" PATH=/opt/puppetlabs/server/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:$PATH

LABEL org.label-schema.vendor="Puppet" \
      org.label-schema.url="https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker" \
      org.label-schema.name="Puppet Server (No PuppetDB)" \
      org.label-schema.license="Apache-2.0" \
      org.label-schema.version=$PUPPET_SERVER_VERSION \
      org.label-schema.vcs-url="https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker" \
      org.label-schema.vcs-ref="a2b1fbbc73177ddc3def23d167f9beb9c3ef9f6c" \
      org.label-schema.build-date="2017-02-21T17:25:14Z" \
      org.label-schema.schema-version="1.0" \
      com.puppet.dockerfile="/Dockerfile"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget=1.17.1-1ubuntu1 git && \
    wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-pc1-"$UBUNTU_CODENAME".deb && \
    wget https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v"$DUMB_INIT_VERSION"/dumb-init_"$DUMB_INIT_VERSION"_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-pc1-"$UBUNTU_CODENAME".deb && \
    dpkg -i dumb-init_"$DUMB_INIT_VERSION"_amd64.deb && \
    rm puppetlabs-release-pc1-"$UBUNTU_CODENAME".deb dumb-init_"$DUMB_INIT_VERSION"_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y puppetserver="$PUPPET_SERVER_VERSION"-1puppetlabs1 && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri r10k

COPY puppetserver /etc/default/puppetserver
COPY logback.xml /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/
COPY request-logging.xml /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/

RUN puppet config set autosign true --section master

VOLUME /etc/puppetlabs/code/ \
       /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/ \
       /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /


# Add the keys and set permissions
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh && \
    chmod 0700 /root/.ssh && \
    echo "$ssh_prv_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    echo "$ssh_pub_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub && \
    echo "Host github.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> /root/.ssh/config


EXPOSE 8140

ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["foreground" ]

COPY Dockerfile /
```

Comment: Post your dockerfile

Comment: sorry i should have also probably mentioned im using Docker CE on wiindows ( linux containers); the dockerfile has been tested on mac successfully

Comment: What is this `dumb-init` for?

Comment: simple init system for containers as one doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File docker-entrypoint.sh is not part of image but it define in Dockerfile.

This file will copy into image when you create image by using "Dockerfile".

You can see example of mysql in github.

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/tree/master/5.6

You can use following command to use Dockerfile for built image

```
docker build -t mysql -f Dockerfile .
```

And you will run image wiht this commend and no need to define as entrypoint in run command

```
docker run --name mysql
```

inside Dockerfile

```
ENV STARTUP_SCRIPT=/usr/local/bin/start-up.sh

COPY nginx/start-up.sh $STARTUP_SCRIPT

ENTRYPOINT $STARTUP_SCRIPT
```

Comment: i made following change to dockerfile:
#ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
now i'm getting :
container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker-entrypoint.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: So you have to make sh script and put all entry commend inside that script.
ENV STARTUP_SCRIPT=/usr/local/bin/start-up.sh

COPY nginx/start-up.sh $STARTUP_SCRIPT

ENTRYPOINT $STARTUP_SCRIPT

Comment: COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/  
    RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh # backwards compat
    ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]